# Can't get text box to take input

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an HTML search form similar to Amazon's. I created the desired look, but when I went to actually try the search the text box wasn't taking any input. At first I thought the text was white or something but after clicking the search button I realized this was not the case. I have tried using Chrome's Inspect Element to see the problem and when I hovered over the input box code, the input box was showing **beneath** the code.

[Here's the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ashraj98/2r06k4sf/)

This is the CSS for the box but I don't see an issue here:

```
    #search-text 
    {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ddd;
    border-width: 0;
    background: transparent;
    }

    #search-box input[type="text"]
    {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 11px 0 12px 1em;
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    }
```

I'm not sure whether the other elements are interfering or if something is wrong with the search box. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add float left to .select-style:

```
.select-style {
    ...
    float: left;
    ...
}
```

Lower the width of #search-box input[type="text"]. 80% seems good:

```
#search-box input[type="text"] {
    width: 80%;
    ...
}
```

Comment: That works brilliantly! If it isn't too much to ask, could you explain why that works? I'm always trying to learn.

Comment: @ashraj98 I'll try to sum it up. Your div "select-style" is a block element, meaning it will always take up the full width of the page. Even if you make it only 200px wide, a margin will automatically grow out of it to take up the rest of the space. BUT, when you make a block element float, it only takes up the width that's necessary. No automatic margin. This allow inline elements, like inputs, to move next to it. BUT only if the inline element isn't too wide. That's why you had to lower the width on your input. See this for more info: http://jsfiddle.net/a_matt_appeared/vgby7cpe/